# Change 'Edit My Profile' text in WP admin

Tags: wordpress

I want to change 'Edit My Profile' text in WP admin at the top right to 'View / Edit My Profile'. I searched a lot of files under wp-admin folder - functions.php, menu.php, nav-bar.php, etc however no success

Please let me know how to change the said text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this into `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', function( $admin_bar ){
    $profile = $admin_bar->get_node('edit-profile');
    $profile->title = __('View / Edit My Profile');
    $admin_bar->add_node($profile);
});
```

Reference: [WP Admin Bar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Admin_Bar).